# Where is Asset/Cardboard/Prefabs @ Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tango

Can not find "Asset/Cardboard/Prefabs" @ "GoogleVRForUnity_1.70.0.unitypackage" linked from "Cardboard SDK for Unity" @ "https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-cardboard-integration#combining_tango_with_cardboard"

Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is not up to date anymore. The current SDK do not have CardboardHead or GVRHead anymore. So you won't be able to find these files with the most recent version of the SDK.

The best I can advice you if you still want to follow this guide is to check for an older version, which you can find [at this link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases).

Comment: still not be found

Comment: @RonSen What did you do exactly? Did you download the content of the git and put it in your project?

Comment: Is the description about "Asset/Cardboard/Prefabs" in the document "https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-cardboard-integration#combining_tango_with_cardboard" right?

Comment: @RonSen My bad. The SDK has been updated, and those files do not exist anymore in the current version. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @RonSen Exactly, yes. The document is not up to date.